# remove line (starting with same 22 charcaters) TAB text file

Tags: notepad++

I have a textfile of 500 000 lines (addresses to members of different clubs) in kind of TAB format (using blanks in stead of TAB, so that all columns are in the ).

Some lines are almost identical (only one column differs -a person can be member in 2 clubs). I don't care which duplicate line is removed since the home address is the same, but I need to remove one of them.

I can find the duplicates in EXCEL (TEXT-TO-CELL and remove them. But then lose the text pattern with the colums, since the format is not TAB och CSV format.

How do write and use regular expression in NOTEPAD++ or TEXTPAD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

1. Open the text-file in EXCEL, converting it into columns using "fixed width" and adding some new columns.
2. used EXCEL to duplicates in one folder and removing those lines
3. exporting the file as "CSV (comma separated differs)" (not as "CSV WINDOWS" since Swedish characters as "åäö" couldn't be saved in this export).
4. Downloaded free test version of ULTRA EDIT
5. Used "CSV to FIXED WIDTH" and gave each columns its width
6. removed ";" from each column

done!